# How to remove dots ggwithinstats in the package ggstatsplot

Tags: r, plot

I use the example from the site, but I want to remove the points so that only the connection of the medians remains.

My code.

```
# for reproducibility
set.seed(123)
library(ggstatsplot)


df_disgust <- dplyr::filter(bugs_long, condition %in% c("LDHF", "HDHF"))

p2 <-
  ggstatsplot::ggwithinstats(
    data = df_disgust,
    x = condition,
    y = desire,
    xlab = "Condition",
    ylab = "Desire to kill bugs",
    type = "np",
    conf.level = 0.99,
    title = "Non-parametric Test",
    package = "ggsci",
    palette = "uniform_startrek",
    point.args = list(size = 0, alpha = 0.5),
    point.path = FALSE,
    centrality.plotting = TRUE,
    outlier.tagging = T,
    ggtheme = ggthemes::theme_map()
  )
ggstatsplot::combine_plots(
  plotlist = list(p2),
  plotgrid.args = list(nrow = 2),
  annotation.args = list(
    title = "Effect of disgust on desire to kill bugs ",
    caption = "Source: Bugs dataset from `jmv` R package"
  )
)
```

The parameter that is responsible for the points, as I understood `point.args = list(size = 3, alpha = 0.5),`but when I set `size = 0` the dots don't disappear.

I didn't find any other parameters that would be responsible for the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the transparency for respective geometric layers to 0.

```r
library(ggstatsplot)

df_disgust <- dplyr::filter(bugs_long, condition %in% c("LDHF", "HDHF"))

ggwithinstats(df_disgust,
  condition,
  desire,
  point.args = list(alpha = 0),
  centrality.point.args = list(alpha = 0),
  point.path = FALSE
)
```

[image]

```r
grouped_ggwithinstats(df_disgust,
  condition,
  desire,
  grouping.var = gender,
  point.args = list(alpha = 0),
  centrality.point.args = list(alpha = 0),
  point.path = FALSE
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: Thank you this suits me, but how to leave the median?

Comment: sry, mean. I'm confused

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to remove raw data points but preserve centrality data points. When you remove geom corresponding to a point, it will remove all points. But you don't need to show the point because the box plot already shows the median. Another solution is that you prepare the graph yourself and use `statsExpressions` package to show statistics: https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/statsExpressions/

Comment: @IndrajeetPatil How about a grouped_ggbetween* plot